# .htaccess remove .php is not working on live site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I simply want to remove .php from my url but for some reason i cannot get it to work. I have gone through every page on google and every bit of code I find is not working.

Some are working on my localhost but none are working on live server.

For example I want www.website.com/the-url.php to go to www.website.com/the-url

And if a user trys to go to www.website.com/the-url.php it automatically removes the .php

This is a snippet that ive got which kind of works on localhost but not live:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

But that doesnt redirect .php , it just lets you view the page at /the-url.php or /the-url

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: who is your hosting provider? It is possible that they have not enabled .htaccess files to work on a per directory basis. you ought to check with them if that is the case.

Comment: ok i will check this

Comment: Try `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]`

Comment: that doesnt take of .php form url

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

backslash on 3rd rule. EDIT: In fact might not change anything. Best to add

Comment: This doesnt redirect .php to /

Answer (score -1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /

   #remove ext
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
   #internal redirect
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
   RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: this shows my url as http://www.website.com/vhost/vhost15/a/l/l/website.com/www/about